# KIE Server REST API to create, retrieve and update rules at runtime

Tags: drools, kie-server

I am trying to use the KIE Server REST API as documented in: https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.27.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#kie-server-rest-api-con_kie-apis.

Specifically, I want to use the API for: "Retrieve and update business asset information".

I am not able to find KIE Server REST API for creating a new rule (business asset) at runtime. I want to be able to add a new rule after the project is deployed into KIE Server.

Can you please point me to the REST API to create, retrieve and update rules using the REST API?

Comment: did you find any reference for this?